# Changing elements in master page from content page in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, master-pages

i have a page called a1.aspx, with the Masterpagefile = a1_master.master. Now the master page has its own divs and images for design purposes. I want a way where when i load a1.aspx, certain chosen 's and images should be hidden (visible=false). how can i do this? 
how can i change the visibility of a div or an image in the master page from the content page?

Answer (score 1):

Declare an Interface for your master page like:

```
interface IMasterPageControls{
 Image MyImage { get; }
}
```

& implement it on your master page:

```
public class MasterPage : IMasterPageControls{
 public Image MyImage {
   get {  
     // whatever it takes to get the correct object...
     return (Image)this.Page
                           .FindControl("nameOfContainer")
                           .FindControl("nameOfImage");
   }
 }
}
```

& then in your page you could do:

```
Image img = (this.Master as IMasterPageControls).MyImage;
```

this will give you the handle of the image & remove some of the problems which @Matthew mentions...

HTH

Comment: Note: this is C# syntax, but the concept remains the same for VB.net

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want to use FindControl and Master, like so:

```
Image myImage = (Image)Master.FindControl("nameOfImage");
myImage.Visible = false;
```

Check [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxwa0ff0.aspx) for more information and samples.

Comment: Please note that this is C# syntax.  You will need to change this to fit VB syntax.  Also note that, according to the link, this will only work if the asp:Image is not inside a ContentPlaceHolder.  If it is inside one, you must find the ContentPlaceHolder first then use FindControl on that to find the asp:Image.

Comment: -1: IMO - letting the page know the "name" or the hierarchy of the control as expressed in the Master page is not good programming practice. Any change to the control name and/or its location will impact all the code. So I don't like the MSDN sample too :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a property for the master page

```
public partial class YourMasterPage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { }

    public bool HideImage
    {
        get { return imgYourImage.Visible; }
        set { imgYourImage.Visible = value; }
    }
}
```

In your content page:

```
(this.Master as YourMasterPage).HideImage = true;
```